# What does Keras Tokenizer num_words specify?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, nlp

Given this piece of code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

whether `num_words=1` or `num_words=100`, I get the same output when I run this cell on my jupyter notebook, and I can't seem to understand what difference it makes in tokenization.

> {'love': 1, 'my': 2, 'i': 3, 'dog': 4, 'cat': 5, 'you': 6}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

word_index it's simply a mapping of words to ids for the entire text corpus passed whatever the num_words is

the difference is evident in the usage. for example, if we call texts_to_sequences

```
sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 1+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[1], [1], [1]]
```

only the love id is returned because the most frequent word

instead

```
sentences = [
    'i love my dog',
    'I, love my cat',
    'You love my dog!'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 100+1)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(sentences) # [[3, 1, 2, 4], [3, 1, 2, 5], [6, 1, 2, 4]]
```

the ids of the most 100 frequent words is returned

Comment: thankyou! I misunderstood it previously thinking that the words that appear less frequently won't be given a word index. so every word is indexed, but while converting to sequences only the most frequently used words are returned?

Comment: it's a simply predefined functionality... you can find more about the usage here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#methods. The logic based on these methods are always the same... make something with the most frequent occurrences, this is a natural law that is often applied in ML. don't forget to upvote and accept it ;-)

Comment: why `1+1`? what happens when you use 1 for the most frequent word?

Comment: @NicolasGervais following the documentation "Only the most common `num_words-1` words will be kept" so +1 seems reasonable. considering our example, Tokenizer(num_words = 1) doesn't return nothing

Comment: Interesting decision from the developers